# Jquery DateTimePicker обязательный выбор времени

Tags: jquery, javascript

Использую для выбора даты и времени компонент Jquery DateTimePicker (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).
Как сделать обязательным выбор времени после выбранной даты? По умолчанию при клике на дату в поле input вставляется выбранная дата и текущее время, а нужно чтобы вставлялось выбранное время.
Спасибо.

Comment: не совсем понятно в чем трудность? На приведенном сайте есть масса примеров со всеми возможными вариантами.

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно, раздели строку регуляркой или слайсом